# Запрещенные (устаревшие) функции

Tags: php

```
Deprecated: Function mysql_listtables() is deprecated in
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтоб эта ошибка не выводилась на экран?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь перед функцией `@`.

Comment: Вы ради прикола что ли галочку "общий" тыкаете?) По ходу уже и на нее надо вводить нижнюю границу по репутации.

Comment: Поправил, случайно нажал, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше подумать о переписании кода с использованием более новых функций, так как это предупреждение о том, что с выпуском новых версий php этой функции уже не будет.